# Independence of two events when one is a subset of the other

Tags: probability

I'm asked to determine if the events $A^c$ and $B$ are independent if $A \subset B$. I believe they are not, so I tried to prove this by contradiction.

Assuming that $A^c$ and $B$ are independent, then it follows that $A$ and $B$ are also independent. Then writing, $A = A\cap B$, I can get: $P(A)=P(A)P(B)$, which yields: $P(A)= 0$ or $P(B)=1$. What can i conclude from here ? Am I in the right path or is there an alternative way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path. An event with probability $0$ or $1$ is independent of any other event. So if $P(A)=0$ or $P(B)=1$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent (even without the assumption that $A \subset B$!). So the conclusion is $A^{c}$ and $B$ **cannot** be independent except in the trivial case where $P(A)=0$ or $P(B)=1$.

Comment: Hi, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3847169/definition-of-zero-measure-sets-in-a-manifold), please?