# Definition of zero measure sets in a manifold

Tags: integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemann-integration

What show below is a reference from the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres.

[image]

So with this results I like to discuss the following definition given by Munkres[image]

So unfortunately I don't understand completely what is above defined. First of all I don't understand who is the function $\alpha$ in the first definition: is it a any coordinate patch or Munkres wanted write $\alpha_i$ rather that $\alpha$? Then I only understand (will it be true?) the equivalence between the two definition only in the case where $D_i=\alpha^{-1}_i(D\cap V_i)$ so if in the first definition $\alpha$ is any coordinate patch I ask to explain the equivalence between the two definition of measure zero set in a manifold: please don't use lebesgue measure theory because I did not study it!!!. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, there appears to be a typo.  In the original definition of measure zero set on a manifold, the definition of $D_i$ should read
$$D_i=\alpha_i^{-1}(D\cap V_i).$$
I am not aware of any errata to this book, but given the fact that there is no function $\alpha$ referenced elsewhere in this definition is very strong evidence that this is indeed a mistake, and that Munkres meant for $\alpha$ to be $\alpha_i$.

Comment: I agree with you. But now I noticed that if $\alpha$ is any coordinate patch then $\alpha_i(D\cap V_i)$ has measure zero and so the arguments adduced after the definition are unchanged; conversely if $\alpha^{-1}(D\cap V)$ has measure zero then $\alpha^{-1}_i(D\cap V_i)$ has measure zero and so $\alpha^{-1}(D\cap V_i)=(\alpha^{-1}\circ\alpha_i)[\alpha^{-1}_i(D\cap V_i)]$ has measure zero. So what can you say about?